# Not understanding at-root syntax in scss

Tags: sass, css-selectors

I have scss files that looks like this:

main:

```
.parentWrapper {
    @import "child.scss"
}
```

child:

```
.myStyle {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

So I end up with this:

```
.parentWrapper .myStyle {border: 1px solid green;}
```

That's fine.

The catch is that sometimes, due to our site and file structure (which is an absolute mess, but that's another discussion...) I need `.myStyle` to work without the `.parentWrapper` class. So I end up with this:

```
.parentWrapper .myStyle,
.myStyle {border: 1px solid green;}
```

I thought that maybe that's what @at-root can help with. So I tried this in my child.scss file:

```
.myStyle,
@at-root .myStyle {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like seeing that `@` at the beginning of the selector.

Is what I'm trying to do with @at-root here doable? And I'm just not using the right syntax?

I realize there's a much better solution here that involves more logical CSS file structures and likely better thought out page templates and all that, but for the sake of this question, I only have access to modify child.scss and nothing else and hoping I can accomplish what I want via the @at-root functionality (or something similar).

I do realize I could just omit the first selector...which in MOST cases would be just fine, as there likely isn't a scenario where a more specific selector is being used that would interfere with things. And that might be the best solution in the end.

Comment: Just put this at the top. @import "child.scss"

Comment: @SteveTomlin I'm not sure I follow...put that import at the top of what?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario I would only use

```
@at-root .myStyle {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

There is no reason to add extra specificity and both are covered by .myClass alone :)